# Compare 'order' to 'products' array and print product names if in the order?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of products:

```
const products = {
    {
        id: item1,
        name: 'My product',
        price: 100
    },
    {
        id: item2,
        name: 'My other product',
        price: 200
    },
    {
        id: item3,
        name: 'My other other product',
        price: 150
    }
}
```

I also have an order state which says which and how many products are in the order. In this instance there is 1 item1 and 2 item2 in the order:

```
const orderState = {
    item1: 1,
    item2: 2
}
```

How can I render the prodcut name and number of times its in the order? Im using React but I think vanilla JS is all thats needed for the solution.

My HTML output needs to be something like:

```
<ul>
 <li>My product x1 = $1</li>
 <li>My other product x2 = $4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can you share sample output format as per your example?

Comment: Neither of these appear to be declared as arrays, but both of them seem like they *should be*.

Comment: maybe your products object sould be an array and you are good to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're *storing* your data is what seems to be giving you difficulty.  First, make the array of products an actual array:

```
const products = [
    {
        id: item1,
        name: 'My product',
        price: 100
    }, //...
];
```

Additionally, what is that `item1` value?  Is that an actual ID of some kind, like an integer?  That's what you'll use to identify the products later.

Then for your "order state", create an object which holds an array of references to the products.  Something like this:

```
const orderState = {
    products: [
        {
            productID: item1,
            quantity: 1
        },
        {
            productID: item2,
            quantity: 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Now that you have a more sensible data structure, you can more easily operate on that structure.  There are a variety of ways to build your output, and how you do it may depend heavily on what other tools you're using (such as template engines and such).  But just to demonstrate the logic, let's build a simple string:

```
var output = '<ul>';

for (var i = 0; i < orderState.products.length; i++) {

    var product = {};
    for (var j = 0; j < products.length; j++) {
        if (products[j].id == orderState.products[i].id) {
            product = products[j];
            break;
        }
    }

    output += '<li>' + product.name + ' x' + orderState.products[i].quantity + ' = $' + (product.price * orderState.products[i].quantity) + '</li>';
}

output += '</ul>';
```

From this you can refactor and improve as needed.  For example, the logic to find the product based on its `id` can be extracted into its own function, or perhaps even reduced to a one-liner using built-in JavaScript functionality or framework functionality.  (`underscore.js` is good for functionality like that.)

But the basic idea is to keep the data structures sensibly organized.  Then the code which operates on those structures becomes trivial.

Answer (score 0):

With below solution you can get the names of selected products as per your question statement.

```
let productsOrderedIds = Object.keys(orderState);
let proNames = [];
for(let pro of products) {
    if(productsOrderedIds.indexOf(pro.id) !== -1){
        proNames.push(pro.name);
    }
} 
console.log(proNames);
```